# AngularJS: accessing/printing a property of a related collection

Tags: angularjs

I've defined two collections in Angular:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, PieceService, TeamService) {
  PieceService.query(function(data){
    $scope.pieces = data;
  });
  TeamService.query(function(data){
    $scope.teams = data;
  });
});
```

pieces is a collection that looks like this: `[{name:'Petra',team_id:2},{name:'Jan',team_id:3}]`
team is a collection that looks like this: `[{name:'TeamA',id:2},{name:'Team',id:3}]`

In the template I am iterating over the pieces collection:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="piece in pieces">
```

**How can I print the teamname of each piece?**

I've tried creating a filter that does this, but as I don't see how I can access the scope in a filter I'm without luck so far.

Comment: Create a function inside your controller that when given a team ID, returns a team name, and bind that to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the sexiest angular way to do it, but I would create a function inside your controller to do the lookup. I also decided to cache the team_id to name lookup, but I realize it's not really necessary for a 2x2 search.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.pieces = [{name:'Petra',team_id:2},{name:'Jan',team_id:3}];
    $scope.teams = [{name:'TeamA',id:2},{name:'TeamB',id:3}];

    var idcache = {};

    $scope.getTeam = function(id) {
      if(idcache[id]) {
        return idcache[id];
      } 

      //cache this
      $scope.teams.forEach(function(team) {
        idcache[team.id] = team.name;
      });

      return idcache[id];

    }        
});
```

I've created a plunkr with the example code.
http://plnkr.co/edit/DsafIfMfARurNeVcl9Qd?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Use team ID as an object key, like this:

```
$scope.teamLookup = {}

// do this in the query callback
angular.forEach($scope.teams, function(val, key){
    $scope.teamLookup[val.id] = val.name
});
```

Then, your markup can look like this:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="piece in pieces">
    <td>{{teamLookup[piece.team_id]}}</td>
    <td>{{piece.name}}</td>
</tr>
```